# mysql - compare data in different rows and columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have one table containing 3 columns. basically 2 but i have generated the 3rd one so i can compare it to the first column.

```
DATE       |TX  |PREV_WEEK
------------------------------
2017-12-05 |52  | 2017-05-28 |
2017-12-04 |95  | 2017-05-27 |
2017-12-03 |123 | 2017-05-26 |
2017-12-02 |20  | 2017-05-25 |
2017-12-01 |66  | 2017-05-24 |
2017-11-30 |2   | 2017-05-23 |
2017-05-29 |250 | 2017-05-22 |
2017-05-28 |28  | 2017-05-21 |
2017-05-27 |85  | 2017-05-20 |
```

what i need is to get a query/table to compare  current days' TX with the previous weeks TX. Therefore i need to add a column with the previous weeks' TX(PREV_TX)  next to PREV_WEEk.

Is there an easy way to perform this using mysql?.

Answer (score 0):

```
select tmp.date,
       tmp.tx,
       tmp.prev_week,
       tmp.prev_tx,
   // you can compare both tx here, like finding difference as follows
      coalesce(abs(tmp.prev_tx - tmp.tx),0) as diff
From
(
select t1.date,
       t1.tx,
       t1.prev_week,
       (select tx
        from table t2
        where t2.date = t1.prev_week
       ) as prev_tx
from table t1
group by t1.date
) tmp 
;
```

Hope it helps!